# Webpack Module Federation handling when the remote app is down/unavailable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, micro-frontend

I am currently exploring about micro frontend with Module Federation. I just forked a sandbox, tried it with success when the both modules available. It has 2 modules, `app1` as the **host**, and `app2` as the **remote** component. But as I think that each modules in module federation should be independent, I tried to make the `app2` unavailable as I didn't start it. Therefore I got error when I run the `app1`, it finished loading with displaying the fallback of the React's `Suspense`, but milliseconds later, it becomes blank as there's error I can't retrieve thus I don't really know.

After that, I tried Webpack's **Promise Based Dynamic Remotes**, then my `webpack-config.js` becomes like this:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require('webpack').container;
const ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin = require('external-remotes-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index',
  mode: 'development',
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    port: 3001,
  },
  output: {
    publicPath: 'auto',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new ModuleFederationPlugin({
      name: 'app1',
      remotes: {
        app2: Promise((resolve) => {
          const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
          const version = urlParams.get('app1VersionParam');
          // This part depends on how you plan on hosting and versioning your federated modules
          const remoteUrlWithVersion = '[app2Url]' + '/remoteEntry.js';
          const script = document.createElement('script');
          script.src = remoteUrlWithVersion;
          script.onload = () => {
            // the injected script has loaded and is available on window
            // we can now resolve this Promise
            const proxy = {
              get: (request) => window.app1.get(request),
              init: (arg) => {
                try {
                  return window.app1.init(arg);
                } catch (e) {
                  console.log('remote container already initialized');
                }
              },
            };
            resolve(proxy);
          };
          // inject this script with the src set to the versioned remoteEntry.js
          document.head.appendChild(script);
        }),
        // "app2@[app2Url]/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      shared: { react: { singleton: true }, 'react-dom': { singleton: true } },
    }),
    new ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ],
};
```

I tried start the `app1` again, then this error comes:

```
$ webpack serve
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/home/projects/github-rl5uyr/app1/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] TypeError: undefined is not a promise
    at Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.eval (/home/projects/github-rl5uyr/app1/webpack.config.js:32:15)
    at Object.function (https://github-rl5uyr.w.staticblitz.com/blitz.01faa899fac41642342f4b7113feacabea334fa1.js:11:114831)
    at Module._compile (https://github-rl5uyr.w.staticblitz.com/blitz.01faa899fac41642342f4b7113feacabea334fa1.js:6:167880)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (https://github-rl5uyr.w.staticblitz.com/blitz.01faa899fac41642342f4b7113feacabea334fa1.js:6:168239)
    at Module.load (https://github-rl5uyr.w.staticblitz.com/blitz.01faa899fac41642342f4b7113feacabea334fa1.js:6:166317)
    at Function.Module._load (https://github-rl5uyr.w.staticblitz.com/blitz.01faa899fac41642342f4b7113feacabea334fa1.js:6:163857)
    at Module.require (https://github-rl5uyr.w.staticblitz.com/blitz.01faa899fac41642342f4b7113feacabea334fa1.js:6:166635)
    at i (https://github-rl5uyr.w.staticblitz.com/blitz.01faa899fac41642342f4b7113feacabea334fa1.js:6:427483)
    at _0x5301a6 (https://github-rl5uyr.w.staticblitz.com/blitz.01faa899fac41642342f4b7113feacabea334fa1.js:11:114450)
```

So, can the module federations run independently each other? If not, what's the real difference as normal library dependencies of monolith front end instead of this sophisticated micro frontend, that I assumed it should be able to work independently like microservices?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are some stuff to be fixed in that promise definition:
first of all it should be defined as a string

app2: `new Promise((resolve) => { ....`
Where the configuration passed for app2 is a string between ` character

As stated in the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-federation/#promise-based-dynamic-remotes)

After that you should change your proxy definition to fetch `window.app2` not `window.app1`.

Finally `remoteUrlWithVersion = '[app2Url]' + '/remoteEntry.js';` is not a valid URL

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and the solution I found was not in the `webpack.config.js` but in the import of the modules in react. The first thing is to install these 2 dependencies

```
npm i react-lazily (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lazily)
npm i react-error-boundary (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-error-boundary)
```

The components or views that you want to import from any of your apps would be called with `lazily`, for example

```
const { Login }      = lazily(() => import("auth/Auth"));
const { Directory }  = lazily(() => import("directory/Directory"));
const { Resources }  = lazily(() => import("resources/Resources"));
const { Statistics } = lazily(() => import("statistics/Statistics"));
```

For the use of `react-error-boundary` I would recommend making a separate component, so I did

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import { ErrorBoundary } from 'react-error-boundary';

export const Externals = ({ children }) => 
{
    return (
        <Suspense 
            fallback="loading...."
        >
            <ErrorBoundary>
                { children }
            </ErrorBoundary>
        </Suspense>
    )
}
```

In my case I made use of this component in my `AppRouter.jsx` file as follows

```
import React from 'react';
import { createBrowserRouter, Navigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { lazily } from 'react-lazily'

import { Authentification, AuthentificationChecked } from '../views/grid/index';
import { Externals } from './Externals';

const { Login }          = lazily(() => import("auth/Auth"));
const { Directory }  = lazily(() => import("directory/Directory"));
const { Resources }  = lazily(() => import("resources/Resources"));
const { Statistics } = lazily(() => import("statistics/Statistics"));

export const router = createBrowserRouter(
[
    {
        path: '/*', element: <Navigate to="auth/login" />
    },
    {
        path: 'auth', 
        element: <Authentification />,
        children:
        [
            { path: 'login', element: <Externals><Login /></Externals>, errorElement: <div>Error al cargar el modulo</div> }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: 'main', 
        element: <AuthentificationChecked />,
        children:
        [
            { path: 'directory', element: <Externals><Directory /></Externals>, errorElement: <div>Error al cargar el modulo</div> },
            { path: 'resources', element: <Externals><Resources /></Externals>, errorElement: <div>Error al cargar el modulo</div> },
            { path: 'statistics', element: <Externals><Statistics /></Externals>, errorElement: <div>Error al cargar el modulo</div> }
        ]
    }
]);
```

Where `<Externals />`  encapsulates my component that I import from any of the `apps`, if it responds correctly in the view the component will be reflected, but if an error occurs the application that imports it will not hang or stay in white, in its case it will show the error message that is included in `errorElement` of each route.

And this without having to do any extra configuration in the `webpack.config.js`, this is how my file looks

```
  remotes: 
  {
    auth: "auth@http://localhost:8081/remoteEntry.js", 
    directory: "directory@http://localhost:8082/remoteEntry.js",
    resources: "resources@http://localhost:8083/remoteEntry.js",
    statistics: "statistics@http://localhost:8084/remoteEntry.js"
  },
```